# How to Pass an argument to a SQL query used in pd. read_sql_query function

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to Run a `sql query` from an `input file`

The `sql query` in the file is given to a `variable` called `myquery`

```
myquery='select * from table where transaction_ID=?'
```

I want to pass `trasaction_id` at run time while executing the `query`

```
trasaction_ID=input("Enter the transaction_ID: \n")
```

Im reading the `output of the query to pandas dataframe` like below ,

I tried to pass the value like this ,but it gives me an error :

```
outdata=pd.read_sql_query( myquery,transaction_ID, conn)

ERROR:ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string
```

Comment: Got the solution by using the below statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the required output by using the below statement.

*`outdata=pd.read_sql_query('select * from table where transaction_ID=&id',conn,params={'id':trasaction_ID})*`

when using the variable instead of complete query also it worked .

```
*outdata=pd.read_sql_query(myquery,conn,params={'id':trasaction_ID})*
```